# Why do we need interfaces to achieve event listeners in java?

Tags: java, interface, event-listener

I have this doubt in Java: when people are writing an event listener they implement an interface and they define a particular function in the interface to achieve a particular task. My doubt is instead of implementing an interface can we just define the function with the an appropriate name.

Also, how interfaces help in achieving event listeners?

Comment: If you have more than one listener, surely you would want to have different functionality for each. If you are using Java 8 though, you could have an `interface` with `default` methods/implementations meaning that you don't necessarily have to override it.

Comment: To successfully listen you need a *call-back* mechanism: a method that can call another *variable* method. Interfaces are how Java allows call-back methods, that is until Java 8, I believe.

Comment: Ah, what do you mean until Java 8 though, lambdas?

Comment: @Alex: I think so, although I am no expert on lambdas, not by any means. I'm not even a newbie yet on them.

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels I don't even know what they are. I was asking just to make sure there were no big things going unnoticed.

Comment: This comes back to the principle of [Polymorphism](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html). An interface is a contract that says "I guarantee that, if nothing else, I will implement the methods described within the interface". This means that when you register a listener with some event generator, it knows that, at the very least, it is safe to call the methods described by the interface. This makes the contract a compile time contract, as the compiler can detect when the contract is broken, otherwise, the event generator would have to "hope" for the right method..

Answer (score 0):

Because many different classes would want to listen to the same event and Java does not allow multiple inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

The Listener interface gives you a lot a implementation freedom.

This way you don't have to implement a specific function in a specific class. Though implementing an interface seemes to be the same, it isn't. The functionality of a listener is just still ja single function, but the function is usualy in a lightweight object. Yet you are able to implement a lot of program mechanics inside a listener, if you need to.

Also, you can change the listeners at runtime. You can't change an overriden function.

There are a lot of good reasons to use [composition (over inheritance)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance) here.

If you really want to understand this, I encourage you to look inside "[Heads first: Design Patterns](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596007124)". The "look inside" feature of amazon contains the complete chapter 1, which explains this pattern greatly.